# Add constructor to std::vector via friend

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not sure if my question is possible or if it might already have an answer somewhere but I'm not sure how to search for it.

I have made some sort of custom container (`MyCollection`). The most important thing is that is has begin() and end() function that return iterators. I want to convert a object of my custom container to an std::vector. What I can use is:

```cpp
MyCollection<double> my_collection;
//... some operations
std::vector<double> std_collection(my_collection.begin(), my_collection.end());
```

But I would like to make it a bit more convenient for myself such that I could do:

```cpp
MyCollection <double> my_collection;
//... some operations
std::vector<double> std_collection(my_collection);
std::vector<double> std_collection = my_collection;
```

Is there any way to add a constructor and assignment operator to an already existing class for which you can't change the class itself?
I think maybe something with friend but I'm not to familiar with friend so I'm not sure if and how it could be used here. Just a no it can't be done is also an super acceptable answer.

For those of you suggesting to make a separate class which inherits and extends std::vector that is not the way I would like to go.

And I'm forced to stick to c++11 for now so I would especially appreciate solutions for that but if it can be done for younger standards I would still be interested

Comment: Best way is just add method: `toVector()`. Do not try over-automatize conversion since it will be harder to read code. You could add conversion operator, but like I said it is better to avoid it.

Comment: If things don't have to be a member, they shouldn't be a member. So just make a free function something like `auto make_vector(MyCollection const&)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. In C++ you cannot extend class without modifying its definition (the header file).

But in your case - you can add ["cast operator"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator):

```
template <typename T> MyContainer {
public:

   operator std::vector<T>() const 
   { return std::vector<T>(begin(), end()); }

};
```

Comment: Nice never heard of this cast operator. Thank you for including the link. I'll try in a bit but I guess this works for both the constructor and the assignment operator right?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add things to `std::vector`, so that approach is out.  One thing you can do is provide a conversion operator like

```
template <typename T>
explicit operator T() const { return T(begin(), end()); }
```

and then you would use it like

```
MyCollection <double> my_collection;
//... some operations
auto std_collection(std::vector<double>(my_collection));
auto std_collection = std::vector<double>(my_collection);
```

This will also work for any type that can be constructed by a pair of iterators.

Comment: I see you templated the whole return type. I guess that means I could use it with any collection. But in this case it will also try to work if I try something like `double std_collection = my_collection` It will give an error of course but I'm doubting whether it would be a readable error. Could that be solved by using sfinae on `T`?

Comment: @C.Binair `double std_collection = my_collection` wont compile as I made the conversion operator explicit.

Comment: Aah yes I see it is explicit. And if I would try `double std_collection = double(my_collection)` I'm just stupid right :)

Comment: @C.Binair I wouldn't say stupid, but yes, you'd be asking for it then.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to your own class:

```
explicit operator std::vector<T>() const {
    std::vector<T> vec(begin(), end());
    return vec;
}
```

Note the [explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit#Notes:%7E:text=A%20constructor%20with%20a%20single%20non%2Ddefault,the%20meaning%20of%20explicit%20doesn%27t%20change.).

Comment: or operator `=`, no?

Comment: @Ivan operator = must be a member function of `std::vector` here, which is not possible for OP to do.

Answer (score 0):

**You can create this functionality.**

Not by adding a constructor to the `std::vector` class that you don't own, but by creating a [*conversion operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to the class you do own.

```
template<typename T>
class MyCollection
{
   
public:
    // Allow any MyColection<T> to implicitly convert to a std::vector<T>
    operator std::vector<T>() const
    {
        return std::vector<T>( begin(), end() );
    }
}
```